# Laravel 8: Seo Friendly Instagram like Username URL system

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I recently worked on usernames for one project and wanted to make a system with usernames right next to domain name just like for example Instagram.com/{username}, Facebook.com/{username} or even Twitter.com/{username}.

**My Route:**

```
Route::get('{username}', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
```

Which works absolutely fine. But I am not able to understand how will SEO detect such dynamic URLs like we can see Facebook and Instagram usernames are at times shown on google and also bing. Is this the right method to do so? Or am I going wrong with this? Someone recently suggested for such URL 301 is supposed to be done, & now I'm quite confused about how in such cases can we do 301 for such URLs?

Comment: For SEO question, you should ask on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: You need to add [tag:opengraph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is fine but I don't understand the part about 301 redirections.

Your concern about crawl engines not discovering unexposed URL's is valid. In fact, it's very unlikely Google Bot will crawl `yourwebsite.tld/{username}` unless you have an external link pointing to it.

To remedy the issue you have two options:

- Have links on indexed pages pointing to new pages you want bots to discover (organic indexing).
- Or, the proper solution, create a [sitemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) at the root of your website to help search engines discover your website pages.

With Laravel there's many different ways to create a `sitemap.xml`. Since your User model is dynamic, you will want your sitemap to be dynamic as well. You can build this feature yourself or you can download an existing package to save time. I personally like [spatie/laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap) but any similar package would do the job.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do we also have some packages for indexing pages? I did think about sitemaps once but then are these two methods safe, from security perspectives, because we are eventually throwing all usernames to a sitemap or indexing it?

Comment: @HardikSisodia A sitemap should only contain public data. Private data is private and shouldn't be indexed or accessible publicly. Are your usernames public or private data? There's no such thing as "a package for indexing" because that doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My usernames are going to be used just like Facebook, Instagram, or any such websites use. Actually am a bit new to SEO and Sitemaps and maybe that's why I asked that. I am simply trying to make my URL SEO friendly by which the user's username can be crawled by search engines or web crawlers. Does insta and FB use sitemaps for usernames which gets crawled and appear on google?

Comment: @HardikSisodia Yes, every website use sitemaps for SEO. Here's Instagram's sitemap file: https://www.ig.com/sitemap.xml Think about it, how can Google or Bing discover urls if you don't tell them where to look? You must provide them with a list of URLs. It's as simple as that.

Comment: https://ig.com seems to be a different domain but yes I did get the concept thank you so much for making me understand it.

Comment: @HardikSisodia My pleasure. Yes my mistake, ig.com is not related to Instagram, but you get the idea.